# Object with values as keys that store each individual object related to it using reduce: Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter, methods, reduce

just working through a problem and was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this issue I'm having. I'm supposed to take an array of objects (a set of parks) and I need to take a key from an object nested within it, use that as a new key and store an array of every object related by that same value we pulled for the key. Here's an example:

I'm working with data that looks a lot like this:

```
const myParks = [
    {
    name: "Garden of the Gods",
    areaInSquareKm: 200,
    location: {
    state: "Colorado"
        }
    },

    {
    name: "Acadia",
    areaInSquareKm: 198.6,
    location: {
      state: "Maine"
        }
    },

    {
    name: "Mountain Pass",
    areaInSquareKm: 400.6,
    location: {
    state: "Colorado"
        }
    },

    {
    name: "Newleaf Forest",
    areaInSquareKm: 150.4,
    location: {
      state: "Maine"
        }
    },
];
```

And I need to take the location.state value and use that as individual keys of a new object, then assign each key a value of the object with a related state. If the state is Maine, the key should contain the entire object with the related state:

```
{
  "Maine": [
    {
    name: "Acadia",
    areaInSquareKm: 198.6,
    location: {
      state: "Maine"
        }
    },

    {
    name: "Newleaf Forest",
    areaInSquareKm: 150.4,
    location: {
      state: "Maine"
        }
    },
  ]
};
```

I was trying to do it like so:

```
function parkByState(parks) {
  let stateParks = parks.reduce((result, park) => {
    result[park.location.state] = parks.filter(park => { park.location.state })
  }, {});
  return stateParks
};
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this properly. I can't change the structure, they MUST be assembled within an object, with the state names as keys, and have an array containing each individual park if the state matches the key. I just seriously don't know what I'm doing wrong. I keep getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Maine')
at <anonymous>:37:35
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at parkByState (<anonymous>:36:26)
at <anonymous>:42:18
```

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and would love if anyone can shed some light on this. I needed to use the reduce() method to assemble the object. I figured using filter to filter the objects into each key would have made sense, but I can't seem to get the two methods to work together properly. You don't have to feed me the answer, but at the very least, please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried several different ways to do this and none seem to work. If I'm missing a key point of how to use these methods, please let me know what I can do to better understand what they are trying to do. I really appreciate all the help and I apologize if this is a dumb question. I'm just trying to understand how to reassemble an array of each park, stored in a key that is pulled from the state of each park. I'm sorry if the question isn't worded the absolute best, I really want to get better at this kind of stuff so I'm just trying to understand what I'm doing wrong here and how I can achieve the desired result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your expected output you only have one state for Maine, why is it just Maine and not also Colorado? In your code, as you expecting to say "give me only Maine" states or is your example output a trimmed-down version of what you're after?

Comment: It's a trimmed down version. It should have a Colorado key with the objects associated with Colorado assembled into an array assigned as the value. I'm sorry if I forgot to mention that or made it confusing. I need both Maine and Colorado to have arrays with each of the related objects inside of them.

Comment: I see. I added an answer below which I think is what you were after, does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The callback that you pass to `.reduce()` should return a value. When you give an arrow funnction a body `{}` it must include `return` if you wish to return a value from it, otherwise, it will return `undefined`. Because you don't return anything from your reduce callback it currently returns `undefined`, so on the next iteration `result` will be `undefined`. This causes your error as you're trying to set a value of `undefind` which you can't do. Moreover, your `.filter()` needs to return a truthy value when you want to keep the value, and a falsy value when you want to discard it.

While you can do some modifications to your code to get the filter to work, I recommend not filtering at all. Instead, check what the current state is of the current park, and if that state is already in `result`, push to the existing array, otherwise, create a new key in result for that state with a new array holding the current state:

```js
const myParks = [ { name: "Garden of the Gods", areaInSquareKm: 200, location: { state: "Colorado" } }, { name: "Acadia", areaInSquareKm: 198.6, location: { state: "Maine" } }, { name: "Mountain Pass", areaInSquareKm: 400.6, location: { state: "Colorado" } }, { name: "Newleaf Forest", areaInSquareKm: 150.4, location: { state: "Maine" } }, ];

function parkByState(parks) {
  let stateParks = parks.reduce((result, park) => {
    const key = park.location.state;
    result[key] ??= []; // set `key` to an empty array if it doesn't exist, (similar to result[key] = result[key] || [];)
    result[key].push(park);
    return result;
  }, {});
  return stateParks;
};

console.log(parkByState(myParks));
```

As you said that you're new to JavaScript, I would do away with `.reduce()` here though. This particular example doesn't really need to use `.reudce()` and can be made more readable by using a for loop. I've also replace the nullish-coalescing operator with an if-statement which might ready more clearly if you're unfamiliar with `??`

```js
function parkByState(parks) {
  const stateParks = {};
  for(const park of parks) {
    const key = park.location.state;
    if(!stateParks[key])
      stateParks[key] = [];

    stateParks[key].push(park);
  }
  return stateParks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without reduce we can do :

```js
const myParks = [
    {
    name: "Garden of the Gods",
    areaInSquareKm: 200,
    location: {
    state: "Colorado"
        }
    },

    {
    name: "Acadia",
    areaInSquareKm: 198.6,
    location: {
      state: "Maine"
        }
    },

    {
    name: "Mountain Pass",
    areaInSquareKm: 400.6,
    location: {
    state: "Colorado"
        }
    },

    {
    name: "Newleaf Forest",
    areaInSquareKm: 150.4,
    location: {
      state: "Maine"
        }
    },
];

const stateNames = new Set(myParks.map(area => {
    return area.location.state;
}));

const collectionsByStateName = {};

[...stateNames].forEach(stateName => {
    collectionsByStateName[stateName] = [];

    myParks.forEach(area => {
        if(stateName === area.location.state) {
            collectionsByStateName[stateName].push(area);
        }
    })
});

console.log(collectionsByStateName);
```